# How to pass data from parent to child angular through an event

Tags: angular, input, components

I need pass data from parent to child on angular. I have a tab group.

```
<mat-tab-group>
    <mat-tab label="Some text0">
        <app-comp></app-comp1>
    </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Some text">
        <app-comp1 [param1]="var1"></app-comp1>
    </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

No problem here. Initially param1 get data correctly when the components are loaded.

Now in the parent component (Component that handle all ), when I edit the value of var1, param1 variable don't refresh it's value into the "app-comp1"

```
export class Component1 implements OnInit {

    @Input() var1             : any;
```

It is posible do that?

Answer (score 0):

You're creating an input property named `var1` in your child and using `param1` 
as the name which is not going to work.

The name of the `@Input` property declared in the Child Component and the name of the Attribute, you're binding to in your Parent Component Template, **MUST BE SAME**.

Change this:

```
@Input() var1: any;
```

to

```
@Input() param1: any;
```

## OR

Change this:

```
<app-comp1 [param1]="var1"></app-comp1>
```

To

```
<app-comp1 [var1]="var1"></app-comp1>
```

Comment: Yes, you are right but my problem is how refresh this var when I edited in other component and all components are loaded.